# How to pass data using javascript in html file, Django template?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to fetch the data (details of the products ordered) from checkout page of HTML I designed. Tried implementing it using javascript but the values are empty when rendered through views.

checkout.html -

```
  <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="col my-4">
  <h2> Your Cart Items </h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for item in cart_items %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ item.product.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.product.description }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.product.price }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>{{ total }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<div class="col my-1">

      <h2>Enter Address & Other Details:</h2>
      <form method="post" action="/thankyou/">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="itemsJson" id='itemsJson'>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputphone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place Order</button>
      </form>
</div>

<script>
  $('#itemsJson').val(JSON.stringify(cart_items));
</script>
```

views.py

```
def thankyou(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        items_json = request.POST.get('itemsJson', '')
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        city = request.POST.get('city', '')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone', '')
        print (request.POST)
        
        order = Order(items_json= items_json, full_name=name, town_or_city=city, phone_number=phone)
        order.save()
        id = order.order_id
        return render(request, 'thankyou.html', {'thank':thank, 'id':id,})
```

The variable (id=itemsJson) is empty when rendered in views. This will be saved along with the form items to create a db entry.
The other form items are populated as expected.

Comment: $('#itemsJson').val(JSON.stringify({{cart_items}}));

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Somehow the itemsJson is still empty while being passed in the tag. I checked the requests header in the developer tools of chrome. Although the same cart_items list is able to populate the table in the page. Am I missing something? some source javascript to be included :/